# Imprimir directamente a impresora conectada mediante JS o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, imprimir, impresora

Imaginaros que tengo una página web y **quiero imprimir** un recibo para el cliente, que al pulsar en un **botón** "Imprimir" de la página me de la opción de elegir la **impresora** para imprimir la IMAGEN que se ve en la pantalla.

Código de prueba:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Formulario de Login - Cliente</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_iniciar_sesion.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo2.jpg">
        <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
            <h2>CLIENTE</h2>
            <h4>INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1">
            <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2">
            <div id="mensaje" align="center">
                <?php if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'true'): ?>
                    <h4><p style="color:red;">¡Sus datos no son correctos!</p></h4>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="iniciar" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"><br/>
                <p class="form-link">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? <a href="registrar.php">Regístrate aquí</a></p><br/>
                <p class="form-link"><a href="recuperar_contrasena.php">He olvidado mi contraseña</a></p><br/><hr/><br/>
                <p class="form-link"><img src="imagenes/entrar.jpg" height="10px" width="10px" alt="invitado"/>&nbsp;<a href="reservar.php">Entrar como invitado</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tendría que añadir un botón "**IMPRIMIR**", ¿cuál sería su código para mandarlo a una impresora e imprimirlo? ¿Existe alguna clase?

Pongo esta imagen como prueba así debería imprimirse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tres preguntas: ¿qué has buscado? ¿qué has intentado? y ¿qué problemas/errores estás encontrando? Te recomiendo que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda, el primer consejo que encontrarás en ese artículo es "**Busca, e investiga**". Esta pregunta tiene ya respuesta en la comunidad ([¡en respuestas y preguntas!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=impresora+javascript)).

Comment: Además, el código y la imagen compartidas parecen no tener nada que ver con la pregunta en sí, creando _ruido_ en la publicación. Lee [ask] y [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con este código puedes hacerlo

```
<A HREF="javascript:window.print()">Imprimir</A>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo debes usar:

[Window.print() - Abre el cuadro de imprimir, e imprime el actual documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

Answer (score 0):

Hablas de imprimir un recibo para el cliente. Como veo que usas PHP en tu código podría sugerirte qué investigues sobre la librería mPDF.
https://mpdf.github.io/
Pero no sé si realmente es lo que necesitas.